# Mongod error (installed with homebrew)

Tags: mongodb

I have installed mongodb with

```
brew install mongodb
```

Created folder

```
mkdir -p /data/db
```

Handle permissions

```
sudo chown -R `id -un` /data/db
```

Run

```
mongod
```

Error log

```
2018-01-06T14:28:51.450+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6120 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Zigas-MBP-2
2018-01-06T14:28:51.451+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.1
2018-01-06T14:28:51.451+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 025d4f4fe61efd1fb6f0005be20cb45a004093d1
2018-01-06T14:28:51.451+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
2018-01-06T14:28:51.451+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2018-01-06T14:28:51.451+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-01-06T14:28:51.451+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-01-06T14:28:51.451+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-01-06T14:28:51.451+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-01-06T14:28:51.451+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2018-01-06T14:28:51.452+0100 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'mmapv1' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'mmapv1'.
2018-01-06T14:28:51.470+0100 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2018-01-06T14:28:51.471+0100 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2018-01-06T14:28:51.494+0100 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2018-01-06T14:28:51.494+0100 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2018-01-06T14:28:51.495+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-01-06T14:28:51.495+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-01-06T14:28:51.495+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-01-06T14:28:51.495+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-01-06T14:28:51.495+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2018-01-06T14:28:51.495+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable toconnect to this server.
2018-01-06T14:28:51.495+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
2018-01-06T14:28:51.495+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2018-01-06T14:28:51.495+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2018-01-06T14:28:51.495+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2018-01-06T14:28:51.495+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-01-06T14:28:51.762+0100 F CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.4 before attempting an upgrade to 3.6; see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-upgrade-fcv for more details.
2018-01-06T14:28:51.762+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2018-01-06T14:28:51.763+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2018-01-06T14:28:51.763+0100 I REPL     [initandlisten] shutdown: removing all drop-pending collections...
2018-01-06T14:28:51.763+0100 I REPL     [initandlisten] shutdown: removing checkpointTimestamp collection...
2018-01-06T14:28:51.763+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2018-01-06T14:28:51.763+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2018-01-06T14:28:51.770+0100 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
2018-01-06T14:28:51.770+0100 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2018-01-06T14:28:51.770+0100 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] old journal file will be removed: /data/db/journal/j._0
2018-01-06T14:28:51.771+0100 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] Terminating durability thread ...
2018-01-06T14:28:51.870+0100 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread stopped
2018-01-06T14:28:51.870+0100 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread stopped
2018-01-06T14:28:51.870+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2018-01-06T14:28:51.883+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2018-01-06T14:28:51.883+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2018-01-06T14:28:51.883+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-01-06T14:28:51.883+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:62
```

Any help would be apprichiated.

Comment: What's in `/data/db`?

Comment: Following files: journal, local, local.0, local.ns, localhost, localhost.0, localhost.ns, mongod.lock,mongodb.log, productiveMeetings-local, productiveMeetings-local.0, productiveMeetings-local.ns, storage.bson

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> 2018-01-06T14:28:51.762+0100 F CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.4 before attempting an upgrade to 3.6; see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-upgrade-fcv for more details.

This is the fault error in your log.

So I guess you have some 3.4 data in your `/data/db`.

1. If you want a clean installation, just remove the contents of `/data/db` and restart `mongod`

or

2. Get a 3.4 mongod

Ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-standalone/

Comment: I have emptied folder /data/db and it is working now, thank you!

Comment: What do you do if you want to keep those colelctions?

Answer (score 9):

The error is telling you that you have mongo 3.4 data inside /data/db but you have version 3.6 of Mongo installed.

To fix this you can use one of the options listed below...

1. Remove the contents of `/data/db` and restart `mongod`. This should probably be backed up or you'll lose your data.
2. Install mongodb 3.4 you can check if you previously installed it using `brew list --versions mongodb` then if a 3.4.* version comes up, 3.4.10 for example use `brew switch mongodb 3.4.10` to move back to that version. If you never had the version installed see this answer to install the older version [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula/4158763#4158763)
3. Use #2 to move back to 3.4 then go into mongo shell using `mongo` and run `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )`. Exit the mongo shell and use the `brew switch` command to switch back to 3.6.