# MongoDB error: shutting down with code:62

Tags: mongodb

Yes, there are other questions extremely similar. However, the reason for this error seems to be different.

I start MongoDB once and it runs fine in the data folder I specify. When I run it again (sometimes), it suddenly does not work anymore and gives me the following output log:

```
2018-01-31T00:31:39.636-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=12248 port=27017 dbpath=C:\Users\20173591\Documents\GitHub\prijzen-volger\data 64-bit host=20173591
2018-01-31T00:31:39.636-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2018-01-31T00:31:39.638-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.2
2018-01-31T00:31:39.641-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 489d177dbd0f0420a8ca04d39fd78d0a2c539420
2018-01-31T00:31:39.641-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1u-fips  22 Sep 2016
2018-01-31T00:31:39.642-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-01-31T00:31:39.642-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-01-31T00:31:39.643-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-01-31T00:31:39.643-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2018-01-31T00:31:39.644-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-01-31T00:31:39.645-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-01-31T00:31:39.646-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "C:\Users\20173591\Documents\GitHub\prijzen-volger\data" } }
2018-01-31T00:31:39.650-0800 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in C:\Users\20173591\Documents\GitHub\prijzen-volger\data created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2018-01-31T00:31:39.651-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3523M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2018-01-31T00:31:39.832-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1517387499:832376][12248:140720232489296], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 12/768
2018-01-31T00:31:39.953-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1517387499:952865][12248:140720232489296], txn-recover: Recovering log 12 through 13
2018-01-31T00:31:40.034-0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1517387500:33883][12248:140720232489296], txn-recover: Recovering log 13 through 13
2018-01-31T00:31:40.162-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-01-31T00:31:40.162-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-01-31T00:31:40.163-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-01-31T00:31:40.164-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-01-31T00:31:40.166-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2018-01-31T00:31:40.167-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
2018-01-31T00:31:40.168-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
2018-01-31T00:31:40.168-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2018-01-31T00:31:40.168-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2018-01-31T00:31:40.169-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2018-01-31T00:31:40.169-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-01-31T00:31:40.169-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-01-31T00:31:40.170-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: The file system cache of this machine is configured to be greater than 40% of the total memory. This can lead to increased memory pressure and poor performance.
2018-01-31T00:31:40.170-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/wt-windows-system-file-cache
2018-01-31T00:31:40.171-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-01-31T09:31:40.181+0100 F CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.4 before attempting an upgrade to 3.6; see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-upgrade-fcv for more details.
2018-01-31T09:31:40.181+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2018-01-31T09:31:40.182+0100 I REPL     [initandlisten] shutdown: removing all drop-pending collections...
2018-01-31T09:31:40.182+0100 I REPL     [initandlisten] shutdown: removing checkpointTimestamp collection...
2018-01-31T09:31:40.183+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2018-01-31T09:31:40.569+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1517387500:568961][12248:140720232489296], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 13/3072
2018-01-31T09:31:40.690+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1517387500:690284][12248:140720232489296], txn-recover: Recovering log 13 through 14
2018-01-31T09:31:40.771+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1517387500:770531][12248:140720232489296], txn-recover: Recovering log 14 through 14
2018-01-31T09:31:41.010+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2018-01-31T09:31:41.011+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-01-31T09:31:41.012+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:62
```

I notice the following message:

```
2018-01-31T09:31:40.181+0100 F CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.4 before attempting an upgrade to 3.6; see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-upgrade-fcv for more details.
```

But this is the first ever time that i'm using MongoDB so there is no way that the data files are not version 3.6. I'm using MongoDB version `3.6.2` and making entries with `Node.js`.

What is causing this problem, and how can I retrieve my data files back? I have lost over 2 million entries twice already which are a pain in the ass to load in the database.

Comment: Why a downvote? Explain please.

Comment: Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381581/upgrading-older-mongo-database-after-unintentional-mongo-version-upgrade) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48127879/mongod-error-installed-with-homebrew) and they didn't help? No vote from me...

Comment: @marekful thanks, the second one offers a remedy rather than a cure. When I delete the data folder, it works fine, but once I restart the mongoDB I get an upgrade error.

Comment: What about the first?

Comment: @marekful I installed mongodb `v3.6.2` yesterday, I don't believe it would downgrade the version between two starts.

Comment: What the first linked answer implies is that there is some difference in the data file format in these versions. I would try... Read the linked doc. Need to set compat. flag.

Comment: You may be dealing with the result of a half-successful upgrade because you failed to meet prerequisites?

Comment: What pre-requisites are needed?

Comment: "Read the linked doc. Need to set compat. flag."

Comment: Have you actually read that tiny short document titled "Upgrade a Standalone to 3.6"? Seriously...

Comment: @marekful no I haven't, because I have no clue what `Standalone` is in this case. The only thing I did is download mongoDB from [here](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community), and run it. Nowhere does this involve an upgrade what so ever

Comment: Well, please **always** read the manual. There you go: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-standalone/#prerequisites

Comment: I get the same problem it work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850004/mongodb-shutting-down-with-code62  @ThomasW

Answer (score 1):

I still do not understand what causes this problem. However, I managed to solve it. [One must downgrade from 3.6 to 3.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-downgrade-standalone/):

- Download the 3.4 binaries ([link](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#previous))
- Run your server with the new 3.4 `mongod.exe` file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after fresh install:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install mongodb
$ mkdir -p /data/db
$ sudo chown -R `id -un` /data/db
$ mongod
```

[see console output when trying to run $ mongod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvYR1.png)

According to [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/exit-codes/) exit code 62 is returned by mongod if the datafiles in --dbpath are incompatible with the version of mongod currently running. A reinstall solved the issue:

```
$ brew uninstall mongodb
$ brew install mongod
```